# Align vertically two tikzpicture in subfloat

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have two sublfoat that I would like to align from the horizontal coordinate line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Using the electrode as einzel lens.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.75) node[above] {$V_{\text{ein}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, -0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\quad
  \subfloat[Using the electrode as repeller.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, -.75) node[below] {$V_{\text{rep}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
  \caption{Potentail diagram of the extraction.}
  \label{fig:potential}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fix spelling of "potential" in the caption before you submit the paper?

Comment: The simplest solution is to change baseline to both pictures, e.g. append `[baseline={(0,-1.3)}]` to both `tikzpicture` environments. To a certain amount, it does not change the right picture but adds white space between the first one and its caption.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add the `baseline` option to both TikZ picture so that the vertical value *y* = 0 will be the baseline from both pictures. But this also displaces the captions, this can be avoided by adding a pseudo-node to the left picture where the right one has the `V_rep` node.

With the `subcaption` package, the same trick can be used.

### Code (`subfig`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\subfloat[Using the electrode as einzel lens.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.75) node[above] {$V_{\text{ein}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, -0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}}\quad
\subfloat[Using the electrode as repeller.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, -.75) node[below] {$V_{\text{rep}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Potentail diagram of the extraction.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\centering
\subfloat[Using the electrode as einzel lens.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.75) node[above] {$V_{\text{ein}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, -0.750);
\path (0,-.75) node[below,opacity=0] {$V_{\text{rep}}$}; % <- Pseudonode
\end{tikzpicture}}\quad
\subfloat[Using the electrode as repeller.]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, -.75) node[below] {$V_{\text{rep}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Potentail diagram of the extraction.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Code (`subcaption`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\subcaptionbox{Using the electrode as einzel lens.}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.75) node[above] {$V_{\text{ein}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, -0.750);
\path (0,-.75) node[below,opacity=0] {$V_{\text{rep}}$}; % <- Pseudonode
\end{tikzpicture}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{Using the electrode as repeller.}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (3.5,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,3.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0, 3.0) node[above right] {$V_p$} -- ++(0.35, 0) -- ++(1.25, -3.0) -- ++(0.25, 0) -- ++(0.15, -.75) node[below] {$V_{\text{rep}}$} -- ++(0.30, 0) -- ++(0.15, 0.750);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Potentail diagram of the extraction.}
\label{fig:potential}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: ...carries the spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

I add a white (invisible) grid to the smaller image to increase its height:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %Grid
    \draw[white] (x1,y1) grid (x2,y2);

    ---
\begin{tikzpicture}
```