# Align two vertical subfloats

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

Basically this question ([Align vertically two tikzpicture in subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136098/align-vertically-two-tikzpicture-in-subfloat)) but for vertically placed subfloats.

I know you can align them with the `baseline` option if they're next to each other, but I don't know how I can align them horizontally.

[image: I'd like the dashed lines to be vertical, i.e. by aligning the nodes.]

I'd like the dashed lines to be vertical, i.e. by aligning the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newcommand{\length}{400}
\subfloat[Bovenaanzicht]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,remember picture]
    % Afmeting van inlet
    \draw[<->] (0, 45) -- (0, -45) node[left,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting outlet
    \draw[<->] (\length + 40, 45) -- (\length + 40, -45) node[right,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting fan
    \draw[<->] (65, .5*65) -- (65, -.5*65) node[left,midway] {65mm};

    % Tube
    \draw (0,45) -- (65, 0.5*65) -- (65+42, 0.5*65) -- (\length, 45);
    \draw (0,-45) -- (65, -0.5*65) -- (65+42, -0.5*65) -- (\length, -45);
    \node (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht) at (65, 0.5*65){};
    \node (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht) at (65+42, 0.5*65){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\par
\subfloat[Zijaanzicht]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,remember picture]
    % Tube
    \draw (0,37) -- (65, 65) -- (65+42, 65) -- (\length, 32);
    \draw (0,0) -- (\length, 0);
    \node (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) at(65, 0) {};
    \node (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) at(65+42, 0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,overlay,remember picture]
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht);
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Profiel van ``Elliptische'' duct}\label{fig:motorschacht_elliptisch}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the documentclass and how you load the relevant packages.

Comment: Edited it for being a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the pictures appear to be of the same size to `tikz`.  This can be done by setting the bounding box completely, or partially via `trim left` and `trim right`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newcommand{\length}{280}
\subfloat[Bovenaanzicht]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,trim left,trim right=200,
    remember picture]
    % Afmeting van inlet
    \draw[<->] (0, 45) -- (0, -45) node[left,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting outlet
    \draw[<->] (\length + 40, 45) -- (\length + 40, -45)
      node[right,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting fan
    \draw[<->] (65, .5*65) -- (65, -.5*65) node[left,midway] {65mm};

    % Tube
    \draw (0,45) -- (65, 0.5*65) -- (65+42, 0.5*65) -- (\length, 45);
    \draw (0,-45) -- (65, -0.5*65) -- (65+42, -0.5*65) -- (\length, -45);
    \node (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht) at (65, 0.5*65){};
    \node (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht) at (65+42, 0.5*65){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\\
\subfloat[Zijaanzicht]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,trim left,trim right=200,
  remember picture]
  % Tube
  \draw (0,37) -- (65, 65) -- (65+42, 65) -- (\length, 32);
  \draw (0,0) -- (\length, 0);
  \node (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) at(65, 0) {};
  \node (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) at(65+42, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,remember picture,overlay]
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht);
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Profiel van ``Elliptische'' duct}\label{fig:motorschacht_elliptisch}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I have reduced your `\length` variable so the pictures fit on the page.

Comment: The problem indeed was that the left hand size of the first subpicture had negative x values for some points and lines. Adding the same things to the second picture "solved" the issue. I also added the `trim left` parameter for the `tikzpicture`'s, now it seems solved. Thank you!

Comment: You can write `trim left=-10` or whatever too.  `trim left` on its own is just a short-hand for `trim left=0`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the first image is wider than `\textwidth` so it protrudes into the right margin. To prevent this, one option is to scale down your `tikzpicture`s (I used `scale=0.85`). Also, notice that you had some spurious blank spaces that I killed in my code using `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\newcommand{\length}{400}
\subfloat[Bovenaanzicht]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,remember picture,scale=0.85]
    % Afmeting van inlet
    \draw[<->] (0, 45) -- (0, -45) node[left,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting outlet
    \draw[<->] (\length + 40, 45) -- (\length + 40, -45) node[right,midway] {90mm};
    % Afmeting fan
    \draw[<->] (65, .5*65) -- (65, -.5*65) node[left,midway] {65mm};

    % Tube
    \draw (0,45) -- (65, 0.5*65) -- (65+42, 0.5*65) -- (\length, 45);
    \draw (0,-45) -- (65, -0.5*65) -- (65+42, -0.5*65) -- (\length, -45);
    \node (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht) at (65, 0.5*65){};
    \node (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht) at (65+42, 0.5*65){};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\par
\subfloat[Zijaanzicht]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,remember picture,scale=0.85]
    % Tube
    \draw (0,37) -- (65, 65) -- (65+42, 65) -- (\length, 32);
    \draw (0,0) -- (\length, 0);
    \node (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) at(65, 0) {};
    \node (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) at(65+42, 0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.250mm,y=.250mm,overlay,remember picture]
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionl zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionl bovenaanzicht);
\draw[dashed] (fanpositionr zijaanzicht) -- (fanpositionr bovenaanzicht);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Profiel van ``Elliptische'' duct}\label{fig:motorschacht_elliptisch}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]