# Align subfigures and captions in a figure that is wider than textwidth

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

Following the advice by G. Medina in question [Figure with two side-by-side subfigures that is wider than textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116792/figure-with-two-side-by-side-subfigures-that-is-wider-than-textwidth), I get the desired figure:
[image]

The trouble is that longer captions de-align the figures:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.654\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{../assets/20180403_all_animal_feed_spectra.pdf}
    \caption{
        short caption short caption short caption short caption short caption 
    }
    \label{fig:all_animal_feed_spectra}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.6\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{../assets/20180403_pls_baseline_rmsecv.pdf}
    \caption{
      10-fold RMSECV of the baseline PLS model with varying dimension of the latent space, trained on the raw data.
    }
    \label{fig:rmsecv_baseline}
    \end{subfigure}%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I guess that the figure needs to be split into two rows: first row to align the images, and second row to align the captions. Furthermore, there should be some free space between the captions.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpfull: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353640/44572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using caption package and minipages:

Edit: (and `caption` package but see @Skillmon's comment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.26\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{
        short caption short caption short caption short caption short caption 
    }
    \label{fig:all_animal_feed_spectra}
    \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.15\textwidth}\phantom{.}\end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{
      10-fold RMSECV of the baseline PLS model with varying dimension of the latent space, trained on the raw data.
    }
    \label{fig:rmsecv_baseline}
    \end{minipage}%
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output with `[t]` for minipages:

[image]

Output with `[b]` for minipages:

[image]

Output with `[c]` for minipages:
[image]

Comment: If you use `caption` just for the `\captionof` command, consider loading `capt-of` instead (as the `caption` documentation also suggests). `capt-of` is much smaller (33 lines compared to 1796).

Comment: Thasnks @Skillmon... I will add the info in the post....

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `[t]` option of `subfigure` if you want top-alignment. You used `[b]` so you got bottom-alignment.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{
        short caption short caption short caption short caption short caption 
    }
    \label{fig:all_animal_feed_spectra}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{
      10-fold RMSECV of the baseline PLS model with varying dimension of the latent space, trained on the raw data.
    }
    \label{fig:rmsecv_baseline}
    \end{subfigure}%
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for ducks :-)

Comment: @Zarko since I wrote that package I use it in every answer where appropriate :)